# How can I avoid some graphical glitches when updating a sprite?

Tags: assembly, x86, sprite, game-engine, emu8086

I'm working on an assembly game engine project.
Is there a way in x86 assembly to clear the screen (CLS-like) fast?
I re-initialize the graphics mode to do this.

```
MOV AH,00H
MOV AL,13H
INT 10H
```

I get created graphic defects on the screen for the continuous update.
Am I doing something wrong?
Like should I put a little delay?

These are the graphical glitches that appear as I move a sprite around the screen.

[image: graphic defects]

In this image you can clearly see the writing "SCORE 000" and the border but everything is out of phase.
This is the screen when there is no continuous refresh

[image: screen if i don't move the sprite]

I refresh because I draw the sprite, so I clear the screen and draw the sprite again in a new position. Based on the arrow keys that are pressed.

Comment: Do not clear the screen. Use double buffering.

Comment: Hi Jester, how can i do it? I know i can change the page, but it work only in text mode and not in graphic mode. How can i change the page of the screen in graphic mode?

Comment: Nice game. Start simple: try writing to an offscreen buffer and then copy it to the framebuffer during a vsync (search on this site for more info, it should be bit 3 of register 3dah or similar). If this is not fast enough (it should be) you can try fiddling with the VGA registers to switch pages but I think you needed to "unchain" mode 13h.

Answer (score 2):

For now, you are animating the sprite by clearing the *entire screen* followed by redrawing the *entire screen*. This produces flicker and artifacts.

> Is there a way in x86 assembly **to clear the screen (CLS-like) fast**? I re-initialize the graphics mode to do this.

Speeding up the CLS is not going to solve it, but restricting the clearing to the surrounding box for the sprite will avoid these artifacts. Whether afterwards you then redraw the *entire screen* or just the combined areas of the old and the new surrounding boxes would only be a matter of 'easy' vs 'more involved' ('easy' because the code that draws the whole screen surely already exists).
Under normal (game) conditions the new surrounding box would be offset by just a few pixels from the old surrounding box. The redraw could be very fast, and perhaps also dead-easy if, apart from the sprite itself, it only has to include those few target-dots I see in the picture that you posted.

---

I just implemented the [method that @MargaretBloom suggested](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76572445/how-can-i-avoid-some-graphical-glitches-when-updating-a-sprite#comment135009172_76572445).
All drawing goes to an off-screen buffer and once a frame is completed it gets copied to the actual video buffer at A000h during the vertical retrace period. I wrote the program in FASM and tested it under DOSBox. Needless to say that it works, but I should mention that I did not observe any need to await the vertical retrace period before copying the private buffer to the official video buffer. May be that it would matter more *outside* of an emulator...

[image: The sprite in action]

```
; Demo for sprite movement
; Assembled with FASM 1.73
; Tested on DOSBox 0.74

        ORG     256

        mov     ax, 0013h       ; BIOS.SetVideomode
        int     10h
; Clear the double buffer
        mov     di, Buffer
        mov     cx, 32000
        xor     ax, ax
        rep stosw
; Draw the border rectangle (once)
        mov     bl, 5           ; Magenta
        xor     cx, cx
.a:     mov     dx, 199
        call    SetPixel
        xor     dx, dx
        call    SetPixel
        inc     cx
        cmp     cx, 320
        jb      .a
.b:     mov     cx, 319
        call    SetPixel
        xor     cx, cx
        call    SetPixel
        inc     dx
        cmp     dx, 200
        jb      .b

        mov     cx, 155         ; SpriteX
        mov     dx, 95          ; SpriteY

MainEx:
; Both pixels are in layer beneath the sprite
        push    cx dx           ; (1)
        mov     bl, 14          ; Yellow
        mov     cx, 140
        mov     dx, 80
        call    SetPixel
        mov     bl, 12          ; LightRed
        mov     cx, 180
        mov     dx, 80
        call    SetPixel
        pop     dx cx           ; (1)
; Sprite is in layer above the separate pixels
        mov     bl, 10          ; LightGreen
        mov     [SpriteX], cx
        mov     [SpriteY], dx
        call    DrawSprite
; Refresh the video ram from the latest info
        call    UpdateScreen

Main:   mov     ah, 00h         ; BIOS.GetKeystroke
        int     16h             ; -> AX
        mov     al, ah          ; Inspecting scancode
        mov     bl, 0           ; Background color is Black
        mov     cx, [SpriteX]
        mov     dx, [SpriteY]
        cmp     al, 4Bh         ; <LEFT>
        je      Left
        cmp     al, 4Dh         ; <RIGHT>
        je      Right
        cmp     al, 48h         ; <UP>
        je      Up
        cmp     al, 50h         ; <DOWN>
        je      Down
        cmp     al, 01h         ; <ESC>
        jne     Main

        mov     ax, 0003h       ; BIOS.SetVideomode
        int     10h
        mov     ax, 4C00h       ; DOS.Terminate
        int     21h
; ------------------------------
Left:   cmp     cx, 1
        jna     Main
        call    DrawSprite      ; Wipes sprite
        dec     cx              ; X--
        jmp     MainEx
; ------------------------------
Right:  cmp     cx, 308
        jnb     Main
        call    DrawSprite      ; Wipes sprite
        inc     cx              ; X++
        jmp     MainEx
; ------------------------------
Up:     cmp     dx, 1
        jna     Main
        call    DrawSprite      ; Wipes sprite
        dec     dx              ; Y--
        jmp     MainEx
; ------------------------------
Down:   cmp     dx, 189
        jnb     Main
        call    DrawSprite      ; Wipes sprite
        inc     dx              ; Y++
        jmp     MainEx
; ------------------------------
UpdateScreen:
        push    es
        pusha
        mov     dx, 03DAh       ; Input Status #1
@@:     in      al, dx
        test    al, 8
        jnz     @b              ; Vertical Retrace in progress
@@:     in      al, dx
        test    al, 8
        jz      @b              ; Awaiting a fresh Vertical Retrace

        mov     ax, 0A000h
        mov     es, ax
        xor     di, di
        mov     si, Buffer
        mov     cx, 32000
        rep movsw
        popa
        pop     es
        ret
; ------------------------------
; IN (bl,cx,dx)
SetPixel:
        push    di
        imul    di, dx, 320     ; Y * 320 + X
        add     di, cx
        mov     [Buffer + di], bl
        pop     di
        ret
; -------------------------------
; IN (bl,cx,dx)
DrawSprite:
        pusha
        mov     si, SpriteD
.a:     imul    di, dx, 320     ; Y * 320 + X
        add     di, cx
        lodsw
        shl     ax, 1
        jnc     .c
.b:     mov     [Buffer + di], bl
.c:     inc     di
        shl     ax, 1
        jc      .b
        jnz     .c
        inc     dx              ; Y++
        cmp     si, SpriteD+20
        jb      .a
        popa
        ret
; ------------------------------
        ALIGN   2
SpriteX dw      0
SpriteY dw      0
SpriteD dw      0010000010000000b
        dw      0010000010000000b
        dw      0001000100000000b
        dw      0011111110000000b
        dw      0110111011000000b
        dw      1111111111100000b
        dw      1011111110100000b
        dw      1011111110100000b
        dw      1010000010100000b
        dw      0001101100000000b
Buffer  rb      64000
```

### Waiting for the Vertical Retrace

> ```
>         mov     dx, 03DAh       ; Input Status #1
> @@:     in      al, dx
>         test    al, 8
>         jnz     @b              ; Vertical Retrace in progress
> @@:     in      al, dx
>         test    al, 8
>         jz      @b              ; Awaiting a fresh Vertical Retrace
> ```

If bit 3 of the Input Status #1 is clear, it means the display is in the display mode.
If bit 3 of the Input Status #1 is set, it means the display is in the vertical retrace mode. What it doesn't tell us however is how much time that is left on that 'vertical retrace period'. That is why the program uses a second loop to wait for the 'display period' to end. Then we'll have the max 'vertical retrace period' time to do the copying.

Comment: On a modern system with a fast CPU, redrawing the whole screen during the vertical-blanking interval should be easily doable for simple retro games (even emulated inside DOSBox if you let it emulate a fast CPU).  Or like Jester and Margaret suggested in comments, double-buffering to give you a whole frame interval to get the next buffer ready and just flip it in the VBI.

Comment: I don't know how can i do double-buffering with INT 10H. Can you help me?

Comment: @Leonardo Added a demo program that uses an off-screen buffer so that the screen can get updated in one go without doing any clearing in the visual area. Waiting for the Vertical Blank Interval is optional.